# Эталонные определения ООП

Tags: ооп, терминология

В интернете можно найти различные определения тому, что такое ООП и прочим основным понятиям (полиморфизм, наследование...).

Однако формулировки не всегда точные, а иногда даже противоречат друг другу или содержат откровенно ложную информацию. Читая литературу Хорстманна или Шилдта я не нашел определений вида ООП это - ... Объект это - ... (хотя возможно плохо искал). Есть достаточно большие тексты, которые проводят аналогии с машинами или столярными мастерскими, но нет определения.

Т.е. меня не устраивает именно абстрактность определений.

Соответственно вопрос, где можно найти определение ООП (объектам, полиморфизму и прочим основным понятиям), которое было дано каким либо общепризнанным светлой ООП. Именно формальное определение, которое было бы однозначным и исчерпывающим.

Comment: ООП и есть абстрактность =)

И уж если вы Шилдта не поняли..ну незнаю.....

Comment: Для расширения кругозора можете ознакомится еще и с [этим](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/). Как можно заметить в IT вообще нет единой точки зрения на ООП

Answer (score 0):

Что такое так называемый "эталон"? Ну во-первых это запись французского слова étalon русскими буквами. Что оно означает у них? Учитывая то, что есть однокоренное слово étale  — неподвижный, спокойный, то можно предположить, что слово étalon — обозначает именно что-то такое постоянное, неизменное, ну по крайней мере на какой-то весьма длительный промежуток времени. Если что не так, то простите меня за мой французский.

Теперь о том, откуда они берутся. Если коротко, то от "думовлиятелей". Это может быть один человек, как например создатель какого-нибудь словаря какого-нибудь языка, так и сообщество оных лиц, которые **договариваются** о том, что то или иное **описание** явления или понятия будет считаться étalon. Подробнее о том, как придумывают и изменяют описание для понятие можно почитать на примере *секунды* в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0).

На бытовом примере попробуйте дать "эталонное" определение понятию *точка*. Как выполните, сверьтесь со списком из той же [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) для данного слова. Всё ли вы охватили?..

Таким образом, если подвести итог, то можно сказать, что любой так называемый étalon в качестве описание чего-либо есть один из многих подобных описаний, но выбранных в качестве наилучшего, либо посредством собрания думовлиятелей на каких-либо государственных или международних собраниях, либо используемый большинством, посредством предложенного описания от одного думовлиятеля. Если же касаться непосредственно описания для понятия ООП, то значит такого описания ещё нет, раз многие из вами узнанных вас не устраивают. Впрочем, таких понятий полно, хотя бы тот же DevOps: им занимаются, но чем именно, описать сложно. Так что используйте наиболее удачный на ваш взгляд, если конечно вы не сдаёте испытание в ВУЗе, ой, тьфу, экзамен конечно же.